# Keyboard stopped showing UIToolbar

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uitoolbar

I have a UITextView on my view, and the keyboard can be dismissed by pushing a done-button on the keyboard's toolbar. This button is also performing a save on the text. The whole thing was working perfectly until the most recent version of my app. I can't figure out what happened. I was suspecting that the problem was setting backwards compatibility of my app to iOS version 11.0. But then i tried with higher development targets again, and the result is the same. I did not touch this view's code when building the recent updates, so I am not sure what causes the problem. Relevant parts of my code :

```
let textView: UITextView = {
    let tw = UITextView()
    tw.font = Font.kohinoorTeluguMedium_20
    tw.returnKeyType = .default
    tw.isScrollEnabled = true
    tw.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
    tw.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return tw
  }()


fileprivate func setupKeyboardToolbar() {
    let keyboardToolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
      keyboardToolBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        keyboardToolBar.sizeToFit()

        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(handleDoneButton))
    keyboardToolBar.items = [doneButton]
    self.textView.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolBar
       textView.delegate = self  
//        self.textView.autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight
    keyboardToolBar.layoutIfNeeded()
    keyboardToolBar.isHidden = false
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupKeyboardToolbar()

    tableView.register(DetailCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    tableView.backgroundColor = AdaptiveColors.tableViewBackgroundColor
    tableView.separatorColor = AdaptiveColors.tableViewBackgroundColor
    setupDismissButton()

    let editButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: LocalizedString.edit, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleEdit))
    editButton.tintColor = .white
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton

}
 @objc func handleDoneButton() {
    let context = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext
    lesson?.notes = textView.text
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch let savErr {
        print("Error saving context \(savErr)")
    }
    textView.resignFirstResponder()
}

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
return true
}
}
```

After reading relevant stackOverflow answers, I have tried calling `layoutIfNeeded()` and `isHidden = false` on `keyboardToolbar`, with no luck. Also gave a try to set `self.textView.autoResizingMask = .flexibleHeight`, with no luck. Also tried to set `keyboardToolbar`'s delegate to `self`, and declaring self as `UIToolbarDelegate`.
Thanks anyone for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have fixed it, it was a stupid mistake I overlooked at some point.
I had some issues with auto layout, so I moved this textView object to my custom cell class, instead of the view controller. Then I was talking to that textView in cellForRow at indexPath method of my VC, but i forgot to setup the toolbar in the cell class. I still had the textView and toolbar setup in the view controller.
I have fixed this problem by moving the setup in the custom cell lass, then making a delegate pattern between the custom cell and the vc, to make note-saving possible.